# Sorting the value in different manner in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have in query, where one column is `hour_id` which contains hour value 1 to 24 for a particular date. Now I need to sort the `hour_id` value like below:

```
hour_id:
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

So, the value will start from 7 then it will ASC order upto 24. Then again it will display from 1 to 5. Can anyone please help to write this sorting mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Add an offset and then take the `MOD`ulus:

```sql
SELECT hour_id
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY MOD(hour_id + 17, 24)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (hour_id) AS
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24;
```

Outputs:

| HOUR_ID |
| --- |
| 7 |
| ... |
| 24 |
| 1 |
| ... |
| 6 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bV2sI3rF)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the conditional ordering :

```
select *
from mytable
order by case when hour_id between 7 and 24 then 1
              else 2 end, hour_id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/aAr9CVvT)

Answer (score 0):

Order by case expression

```
order by case when (hour_id between 7 and 24) 
                   then hour
              else hour_id*100 
        end
```